# how to display jquery messages on right side of the field in red color?

Tags: jquery, jsp

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#loginForm").validate({
    
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: 
        {
            userid:
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },

            password:
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            
            confirmpassword:
            {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            
            role:
            {
              required: true,
            }
        },
        
        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: 
        {
            
         userid: 
            {
       required: "Please provide a user name",
       minlength: "Your user name must be at least 5 character",
            },

            password: 
            {
       required: "Please provide a password",
       minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 character",
            },
            
            confirmpassword: 
             {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 character",
        equalTo: "your password should be same as above"
             },
        },
        
        submitHandler: function(loginForm)
        {
            if ($("#loginForm").valid())
            {
             loginForm.submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
tml PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ include file="include.jsp" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id='formlogin'>

<form method="post" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="page2.jsp" class="message">
  <table cellpadding="8" border="0" width="15" cellpadding="10" valign="top" >
  
  <h3> Add a new user </h3>
  
   <tr>
    <td align="center">User ID:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="10" size="20" type="text" name="userid" id="userid" /></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Password:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="10" size="20" type="password" name="password" id="password"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Confirm Password:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="10" size="20" type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Role:</td>
    <td><select name="role" id="role" title="Please select role" font:color="red"> 
     <option value="">Select a specific role</option>
     <option value="OPS(Operational)">OPS(Operational)</option>
     <option value="Helpdesk">Helpdesk</option>
   </select></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4"><input tabindex="7" type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>     
   </tr>
   
   
   
   </table>    
  </form>
 </div>
<script>
 // just for the demos, avoids form submit
 jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
   debug: true,
   success: "valid"
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i have provided both the codes.
login.jsp and login_validate.js
I have included all the jquery libraries in the include.jsp file.
Please help me about how to display error messages on the right hand side of the field and that too in red color.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsbin.com/xiyirebuho/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you nivedita madam.
Your given links works very fine.
But i want to keep html, css and jquery code separately in each file.
In your given link, the same is code is merged in one file which I dont want.
Please help me in other way if you can.
Once again thank you so much maam.

Comment: you can put the code in sepate files. Put the code inside '<script>' tag file in .js file and the code in `<style>` tag in a css file. See this: https://jsbin.com/kazorigaqi/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thank you maam for the kind response.
But still my problem is not solved entirely.
because i want the validations to be in jquery and not in javascript.
and not only i have form like things on the web page but also i have many more things on the same.
so i want to display form in exactly in the center as label doesnot contain alignment attribute.

Comment: Can you make a proper working JSbin of your current code?

Answer (score 0):

can you try with giving this style to error label

```css
label.error{
    color:#ED7476;
    margin-left:5px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank u sir for your kind reply. I have tried it. By implementing your code only error message is coming in red color. But it is not coming on the right side of the field. Once again please help me sir.

Comment: can you share your code in https://jsfiddle.net/ with properly jquery validation plugin then i can check why that's not working

Comment: I have shared my code on jsfiddle.net
But i m not sure whether it is successfully uploaded as i m new to this stuff. 
following is the link for the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/java13/s85a5j4k/

Comment: can you remove this <table cellpadding="8" border="0" width="15" cellpadding="10" valign="top" > and only keep <table> so that form can have enough space on right side to show the error messages

Comment: yeah sir 
it is working
but the problem is :
after clicking on submit button the form gets shifted to left side which should not b the case.
so can you please help for that?

Comment: Can you give some width and margin to #formlogin div wrapper and place accordingly so that it won't shift. I can't help you much because i am not sure about your page layout. If you could share your url then i can check what's the issue

Comment: If i add width and margin then error message displays on below of the field. and I have many more files as i m working on project. so i m also not getting which file to post here.

Comment: Increase the width of the container to maximum to give enough space to error messages else it will break down to next line